# Resume results in black screen (LUbunutu 22.04, same result with swap partion and swap file)

Tags: swap, hibernate, touchscreen, resume

Previously I used a swapfile after a fresh LUbunutu 22.04 install. I configured UUID etc in the startup parameters. Because resume resulted in black screen I changed to a swap partition. (see also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

But swap partition resulted in back screen as well.

secure boot disabled in bios.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=ab020e6e-ea8d-4cfd-81ce-189c33789b47"

sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume  
RESUME=UUID=ab020e6e-ea8d-4cfd-81ce-189c33789b47

/etc/sysctl.d/local.conf
vm.swappiness=10
```

I checked many ask ubuntu posts related to this topic but none of them seem to work. Your help would be very much appreciated!

Note: I can provide excerpts of /var/log/syslog from the resume in case you tell me which parts are relevant